# How to compute inverse of a multi-map

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a Scala Map: 
    x: [b,c]
    y: [b,d,e]
    z: [d,f,g,h]

I want inverse of this map for look-up.
    b: [x,y]
    c: [x]
    d: [x,z] and so on.

Is there a way to do it without using in-between mutable maps

If its not a multi-map - Then following works:

```
typeMap.flatMap { case (k, v) => v.map(vv => (vv, k))}
```

Comment: Can you please mark this as completed and select an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: fixed answer to include what Marth rightfully pointed out. My answer is a bit more lenghty than his as I try to go through each step and not use the magic provided by flatMaps for educational purposes, his is more straightforward :)

I'm unsure about your notation. I assume that what you have is something like:

```
val myMap = Map[T, Set[T]] (
  x -> Set(b, c),
  y -> Set(b, d, e),
  z -> Set(d, f, g, h)
)
```

You can achieve the reverse lookup as follows:

```
val instances = for {
  keyValue <- myMap.toList
  value <- keyValue._2
}
yield (value, keyValue._1)
```

At this point, your instances variable is a List of the type:

```
(b, x), (c, x), (b, y) ...
```

If you now do:

```
val groupedLookups = instances.groupBy(_._1)
```

You get:

```
b -> ((b, x), (b, y)),
c -> ((c, x)),
d -> ((d, y), (d, z)) ...
```

Now we want to reduce the values so that they only contain the second part of each pair. Therefore we do:

```
val reverseLookup = groupedLookup.map(_._1 -> _._2.map(_._2))
```

Which means that for every pair we maintain the original key, but we map the list of arguments to something that only has the second value of the pair.

And there you have your result.

(You can also avoid assigning to an intermediate result, but I thought it was clearer like this)

Comment: The way you're constructing `instances` translates to a `.flatMap`. `The type of the resulting collection is guided by the static type of immutable map.` (see [#flatMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map)), which means `instances` is a `Map[A,B]` and that you'll lose some tuples in the process.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it so it reflects the correct way in a more step-by-step process, but I also upvoted your answer because it's more direct

Comment: Also - groupedLookup.map(_._1 -> _._2.map(_._2)) can just be -                   groupedLookup.mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2))

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simplification as a function:

```
def reverseMultimap[T1, T2](map: Map[T1, Seq[T2]]): Map[T2, Seq[T1]] =
  map.toSeq
    .flatMap { case (k, vs) => vs.map((_, k)) }
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

The above was derived from [@Diego Martinoia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385324/diego-martinoia)'s answer, corrected and reproduced below in function form:

```
def reverseMultimap[T1, T2](myMap: Map[T1, Seq[T2]]): Map[T2, Seq[T1]] = {
  val instances = for {
    keyValue <- myMap.toList
    value <- keyValue._2
  } yield (value, keyValue._1)

  val groupedLookups = instances.groupBy(_._1)
  val reverseLookup = groupedLookups.map(kv => kv._1 -> kv._2.map(_._2))
  reverseLookup
}
```